# display epoch date-time as formatted date in Date Input element (html date picker)

Tags: html, angular, datetime, binding, epoch

In angular
want to display epoch date-time as formatted date in Date Input element (html date picker)[dop show in input using binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4umUP.png)
I can show this by using function and set in input but want to set it directly using binding

have tried multiple solution but every solution is providing manually set data after converting into element
want to use data binding as we are using directly in  textview for other string